# how to retrieve array variable elements passed as a command line argument to Expect script

Tags: perl, expect

I have a Perl script that invokes an Expect script with command line arguments passed to it.
I wanted to know if we pass an array variable as argument, how do we retrieve the array variable in expect script? 
For a simple variable passed as command line argument  : set var [lindex $argv 0] is used. 
I need to know how to access array variable in similar fashion and use its elements in the expect script. a sample code would be of great help!
looking forward for responses,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The expect global variable `$argv` is a list (i.e. a perl array). If you want to capture it in a different variable:

```
set myvar $argv
```

Or use it directly

```
foreach item $argv {
    do something with $item
}
```